# How to :delight major mode strings when using powerline with use-package?

Tags: mode-line, powerline, mode-line-format, delight

I am unable to `:delight` major mode strings (in the mode-line) from `use-package` because I am intializing `powerline` with `use-package` itself.

My guess is that the `:delight`'ing part occurs at the wrong time and `mode-line-format` is set without the updated major mode strings (it works fine if `powerline` is `:disabled`).

What is a good approach to solve this issue?

Here is my <s>[init-mode-line.el](https://bitbucket.org/angrybacon/dotemacs/src/31ee2aff0277f51b8f1207ad34decb622ffa7825/lisp/init-mode-line.el?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default)</s> for reference. New link: [init-mode-line.el](https://bitbucket.org/angrybacon/dotemacs/src/94a35d6bb2a5f1e007d40b644666a46071bd3f44/lisp/init-mode-line.el?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default).

Comment: I don't actually know how the use-package integration works, but I can see in the commented `(delight...)` form in your link that you are missing the argument `:major` from each of the major mode declarations. Please refer to the documentation at https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DelightedModes

Comment: That commented part wasn't being used (some old copy pasta). I use `delight` in conjunction with `use-package` which allows us that `:delight` shortcut: [it is used the same way `diminish` is used](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package#diminishing-minor-modes). However, as I mentioned, it works pretty fine when I disable the powerline.

Comment: Well you did point to that file "for reference", and that commented block contains the *only* instance of the word "delight" in the file. Show us the code you're *actually* trying to use. Showing a version you're not using helps no one.

Comment: As a example, see [init-css.el](https://bitbucket.org/angrybacon/dotemacs/src/94a35d6bb2a5f1e007d40b644666a46071bd3f44/lisp/init-css.el?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default). The issue doesn't live in how I use the keyword `:delight` but how I set `mode-line-format`. That's why I only showed [init-mode-line.el](https://bitbucket.org/angrybacon/dotemacs/src/94a35d6bb2a5f1e007d40b644666a46071bd3f44/lisp/init-mode-line.el?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) (updated link). Sorry if this was unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that `powerline` and `delight` are not directly compatible; but I've made a change to [`delight`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DelightedModes) (new version 1.04) to make such integration possible in general, and I've added a [`delight-powerline`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DelightedPowerLine) library which builds on top of that to handle powerline specifically.

*Original answer follows...*

---

Well I tried your config. My first comment is that you seem to be specifying the *default* mode names in most of your :delight specs, which is kinda weird. e.g. org-mode *already* uses "Org" as its mode-name -- there's surely very little point in using `:delight org-mode "Org"`.

*However* I can confirm that delight is still working for major modes with powerline enabled, because if I visit an org-mode buffer and check `mode-name` it tells me `(inhibit-mode-name-delight "Org" "Org")` (normally those two values wouldn't be identical, of course, but see above...)

This is delight's way of getting the mode line to show the delighted value without *also* showing that custom value in other contexts (e.g. `M-x describe-mode` which also displays `mode-name`).

This suggests to me that powerline is calling `format-mode-line` explicitly, which is delight's trigger (via advice) to show the *original* version of the name. (n.b. It's slightly unintuitive, but `format-mode-line` is *not* called by the normal mode-line display code, but provided so that *other* things can render mode line constructs.)

That's an incompatibility between the two libraries, I'm afraid.

You can *disable* delight's advice (after it has been loaded) like so:

```el
(ad-disable-advice 'format-mode-line 'around 'delighted-modes-are-glum)
(ad-activate 'format-mode-line)
```

This will fix your powerline output, but also means that anything else which displays a major mode's mode-name will also show the delighted version. That's probably still preferable for you, though.

Better would be some advice to act *only* when powerline is being called. This wasn't an option for the standard mode line rendering, but could certainly be done for cases like this.

I've uploaded a [`delight-powerline.el` integration library](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DelightedPowerLine) to the EmacsWiki.

Note that it requires the equally-new version 1.04 of [`delight.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DelightedModes).

Comment: I want to have the upper hand on how things look (and thus avoid the - very unlikely - renaming of the modes I use). More than that, having a ready to be customized block for every package (although suboptimal) suits me best :). I have tried your snippet and it does the job, thank you. On a third note, why use `defvar` + `setq` for `inhibit-mode-name-delight`? What's the difference with `setq-default` only in that case?

Comment: That was because delight.el itself did not declare the variable already. I've resolved that in the updated libraries, though -- see the link in the revised answer.

Comment: Ok, will update ASAP thanks :) it needs a bit of time to be ready for an update through `list-packages` I guess. But my question was more of an educational purpose: it was working with `setq-default` only as well.

Comment: Since the introduction of lexical binding, it's good form to `defvar` all dynamic variables in case they end up being referred to in a library which uses lexical binding. I don't actually know whether `setq-local` on an undeclared variable will also force it to be dynamic. I had simply noted the issue, and went with the standard approach.

Comment: Oh ok, I see. Thanks for the clarification, and your work on delight.el :)